# page fails to load when refreshed when query data is passed with router.push in nextjs

Tags: next.js, next-router

```
router.push({
 pathname: "/singleview",
 query: { data: JSON.stringify(props) },
});
```

Page failed to load (This page isn’t working HTTP ERROR 431) when refreshed.

Comment: is that exact error message or it says request headers too large. that is what 431 code is

Comment: Yes its is the exact error message, it is a similar case when we pass query data with <Link as='/someUrl'> and use 'as' property in it and on refresh the query data get lost.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].